# Use the 2D pointer without allocation

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the following C code, I allocate, initialize, and define values for `**c`. I want `**assign` to take `**c`'s values. But I only declare a 2D pointer for `**assign`, no memory allocation, and the code runs successfully and print out the same results as `**c`. I don't know why?

```
int main(){

    int i,j;
    float **c=NULL, **assign=NULL;
    c = (float **)calloc(2,sizeof(float *));
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        c[i] = (float *)calloc(3,sizeof(float));
    }

    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
            c[i][j] = i+j;
            printf("c[%d][%d]=%f\n",i,j,c[i][j]);
        }
    }

    assign = c;
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        for (j=0;j<3;j++){
            printf("assign[%d][%d]=%f\n",i,j,assign[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c` and `assign` are pointers, not arrays.  Code is simply assigning a pointer with `assign = c;`.

Comment: Two pointers can point to the same memory. As long as the memory being pointed to has been properly allocated this is perfectly safe. You don't have to allocate separately for each pointer. Having said that, note that in C saying that "the code runs successfully" is not always proof that the code is correct. Undefined behavior often looks like code that "runs successfully" *most* of the time.

Comment: @JohnColeman So you mean the code is correct, but my words are not reasonable?

Comment: @james I don't know if your code is correct. I didn't run it or think about it very deeply. Nothing jumps out at me. I just wanted to sound a note of caution to not read too much into the fact that the code seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found.

When you allocate:

```
c = calloc(2,sizeof(float *));
```

You are assigning the starting address for the new block of memory to `c`. In other words `c` points to the location in memory where the first (of two) pointers you allocated can be found.

When you assign (verb):

```
assign = c;
```

You are setting the value held by `assign` to the value held by `c`. (and what does `c` hold? -- the address of the block of memory you allocated with `calloc`). So `assign` now holds the same address as `c`, e.g. `assign` now points to the first (of two) pointers you allocated. So `assign` and `c` now both hold the same address as their value and you can use either one to reference what is stored there.

**note:** there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). Further, if you use the derefernced pointer to set the *type-size* for the allocation, you eliminate the chance of getting it wrong, e.g.

```
c = calloc (2, sizeof *c);
```